# How can I find dependent tables and their dependents of a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, ssms

```
SELECT         
    c.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    cu.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencingTable, cu.COLUMN_NAME AS 
    ReferencingColumn,
    ku.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencedTable, ku.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencedColumn
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS c
INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ku ON ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE 
    ku.TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

With this query, I'm able to find the dependents but I'd further like to know the dependents of their dependents recursively and ultimately reach a point where I end up with a table with no dependencies at all. i.e. With no foreign key(s)

Comment: You would need a recursive cte for this.

Comment: You also need to decide which DBMS you are using. The way to answer this is vastly different from sql server and oracle.

Comment: Can you help me with the CTE as the query I've used only provides be dependents of the table but not their dependents?

Comment: Let's take a different approach. What are you trying to find? I think there may be a better way to accomplish your objective but not 100% sure what that objective is.